# Sinning while working halal job

Tags: halal-haram, salat, sin, work

If someone is sinning while doing his work does that affect his income?
For example. Being drunk/half drunk while working on a (halal)freelance project. Assuming that he does the job fine and the client accept it, will the income still halal?

Being drunk is just an example. It could also be, leaving prayer when he is working, listening to music while he is working (for those who consider music haram)